# Entity Framework DynamicProxies length name of class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository

I have Repository and try get object from base. But, type of class:

> System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.**FoundationInformatio**_2B2257689287A8D593FBF2013945969F4E7612CD66850A8D4A6D6CAAC5BFF101

My class have type of: **FoundationInformation**

I need full name. Why length name of class is 20 characters in DynamicProxies? How get full name of class?

Comment: @JoelRamosMichaliszen, yes. I solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided:

```
ObjectContext.GetObjectType(obj.GetType());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try some thing like some extension methods:

```
public static Type GetNonProxiedType(this object obj)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetNonProxiedType();
}
public static Type GetNonProxiedType(this Type type)
{
    return IsProxied(type) ? type.BaseType : type;
}
public static bool IsProxied(this Type type)
{
    return type.Namespace.Contains("Proxies");
}
```

So then you just code that `entity.GetNonProxiedType().FullName`

Hope be useful.